# Akka Futures guidance

Tags: java, multithreading, akka

I'm trying to use Akka Futures to read several files and pass each line to a callable.
My callables are parsers for a specific file.  So people.txt might populate objects of type Person.
Each line can contain upwards of 50 fields that each need validation and operations to populate the object.

So I'd like to get something like
`Future <Iterable<Person>>` back, but not sure how I get that from

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(getInputStream(), "UTF-16"));

while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    // call callable here for each line
    // PersonParser that implements Callable<Person>
}
reader.close();
```

How can I structure this to get this in my future object.  Any advise is welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`Futures.sequence`](http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.1.2/akka/dispatch/Futures.html#sequence%28java.lang.Iterable,%20scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext%29) method to create a `Future<Iterable<Person>>` from a `Iterable<Future<Person>>`:

```
List<Future<Person>> personFutures = new ArrayList<Future<Person>>();
BufferedReader reader = 
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getInputStream(), "UTF-16"));

while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   PersonParser parser = new PersonParser(line);
   personFutures.add(Futures.future(parser, system.dispatcher()));
}
reader.close();

Future<Iterable<Person>> personsFuture = 
    Futures.sequence(personFutures, system.dispatcher());
```

Comment: Sorry for the downvote.  I fat fingered it on my phone and I don't seem to be able to change it now unless you edit it.  If you edit your comment I will upvote it for you.  Sorry again.